# Surprise in measuring UBIFS on NAND performance in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, performance, ubifs

I am working on an embedded Linux system (Linux-5.10.24), and there is a raw NAND FLASH as storage device on which UBI/UBIFS is used as file system.

Now I am trying to measure and compare the UBIFS performance with and without compression, so I did following tests.

And my expectation is file reading/writing with compression should NOT be better than without compression.

1. Using `dd` to test UBIFS reading and writing.
   Firstly, ran `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/aaa bs=131072 count=128` to generate file of `aaa` to be read and written.
   Here is the result.

   - Mount UBIFS with compression enabled (default mode),
     `Writing: 2.6MB/s, Reading: 8.3MB/s`
   - Mount UBIFS without compression (-o compr=none),
     `Writing: 2.7MB/s, Reading: 8.2MB/s`

   I tried many times, and got the similar results.
   To my surprise and out of my expecation, the performance with and without compression is similar!
2. Using a C program to measure the time consuming on file reading from UBIFS with and without compression.
   Here is the testing results.

   - Mount UBIFS with compression enabled (default mode), reading `1707378112 bytes took 18134 ms`.
   - Mount UBIFS without compression (-o compr=none), reading `1707378112 bytes took 19222 ms`.

To my surprise and out of my expectation, file reading with compression is better than without compression.

So I am wondering if my testing is correct or not. And if my testing results are correct or not? If not, what is the right way to measure/compare UBIFS performance with and without compression?